# preserving UI in post filter aggregated faceted search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm moving a sql server product catalog over to elasticsearch and want to preserve how the ui currently allows the user to navigate the options. I am using aggregates with post filter but cannot get the selected options siblings to show up in the aggregates.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is from the [elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html).

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search
{
"size" : 0,
"query": {
    "match": {
        "make": "ford"
    }
},
"post_filter": {    
    "term" : {
        "color" : "green"
    }
},
"aggs" : {
    "all_colors": {
        "terms" : { "field" : "color" }
    }
}
}
```

So, the user has clicked on the green option and the returned documents show only green ford cars, but the aggregates list all of the colors available for ford with their counts, which can be added to a ui.

All of this is ok. But, there are many makes of car other than ford. If I added a 'makes' aggregate, then this query will only return ford in the aggregates list. If building the navigation ui dynamically from the returned results (as I am), then there would be no way to place all the other makes of car into the ui, unless I queried elasticsearch many times to build up my ui - which I don't want to do.

If I changed the query to a match-all and added the query to the post filter, then I would get the full list of car makes in the aggregation, but the counts would always be a global count from the match-all query and not reflective of the drill-down count.

Is it possible to do this with elasticsearch? I've gone through all the documents - several times, and tried many different query formats, but nothing has produced quite the right results so far.

Comment: I might be a bit late but I found this post to be helpful in understanding how to accomplish what you're basically after [faceted search using Elasticsearch](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/faceted-search-using-elasticsearch/)